# Getting multiple duplicate kotlin classes errors with a Java app in android studio

Tags: java, android, duplicates

When trying to build my Java app, I get multiple duplicate Kotlin classes error. Classes in error are said to be declared in both "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.20" and "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.6.21".
My dependencies are :

```
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.1'
    implementation 'org.mapsforge:mapsforge-map-android:0.19.0'
    implementation 'com.caverock:androidsvg:1.4'
    implementation 'org.mapsforge:mapsforge-poi-android:0.19.0'
    implementation 'org.mapsforge:sqlite-android:0.19.0'
    implementation 'org.mapsforge:mapsforge-themes:0.19.0'
    implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:6.1.16'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.1.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity:1.7.2'
    implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.6.0'
```

Using Gradle plugin version 8.0.2 and Gradle version 8.2, build tool version 34.0.0.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add this in `build.gradle` right after declaring your dependencies like this:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity:1.7.2'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.mlkit:image-labeling:17.0.7'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0-alpha01'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.15.1'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxandroid:3.0.2'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxjava:3.1.6'
}

configurations.implementation {
    exclude group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin', module: 'kotlin-stdlib-jdk8'
}
```

I faced a similar error few months ago and this solved it for me.

Comment: Welcome. I couldn't take full credit as I also got it fixed from someone else but couldn't find the article at the moment. Anyways, I am glad I could help.